# Hearing notification sounds while Windows 10 focus assist is enabled

Tags: windows-10, notifications, slack

I love the Windows 10 focus assist feature, it really does filter out most notifications and helps me focus.

I am having one issue with it though, some applications still play a notification sound even though focus assist does disable the notification banner. I have noticed this issue mainly with Slack. I am not sure if this is an issue in Slack implementation or an issue with focus assist.

The notification sounds are still distracting even though banners are not shown. I am aware that I can mute certain applications or even the entire PC, but I would really like to be able to just enable/disable focus assist and that's it.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I have also noticed the same problem happens with Skype as well, sometimes I can hear skype notification sounds as well, although sometimes it is muted.